# Error while enabling monitor mode

Tags: 15.04, ifconfig

Interface   Chipset     Driver

wlan0       Broadcom    wl - [phy0]mon0: ERROR while getting interface flags: No such device

```
            (monitor mode enabled on mon0)
```

What does this error means is there any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
sudo ifconfig wlan0 down
sudo iwconfig wlan0 mode monitor
sudo ifconfig wlan0 up
```

then just do

```
iwconfig
```

and see if it works.

Note that you should name your device instead of `wlan0` if it is different. This was just used as an example. You could and should, if you ask me, install aircrack-ng and rather use the following command:

```
sudo airmon-ng start wlan0
```

which will give you an image device called `mon0` that will be in the monitor mode while your `wlan0` will stay in managed mode. Works much better this way.

Comment: Hey mate I already used that airmon-ng start wlan0 from there it shows that error.

Comment: Could be that your wifi device doesn't support monitor mode.  Try `sudo lshw -c network` and then search online to find out.